# IE 11 beforeunload event doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, events, browser, internet-explorer-11, onbeforeunload

I found the following case where using beforeunload event in IE11 results in a strange behaviour where you can't close the IE window or tab.

To reproduce, run the following code in the browser console:

window.onbeforeunload = function() { return false;}

This should trigger the confirmation popup when refreshing the page or trying to quit the page/browser.
Refreshing the page is fine, it always triggers the popup.
But the tab/browser closing fails(you don't get popup because event is not fired - you can't close the browser by clicking close icon) if tou do this:

Open IE 11, with only one tab. 
Run the code in the console (for this tab). 
Try to close the tab - - - all good, you get popup - - - don't leave the page. 
Open a second tab. 
Go to the first tab, and again try to close it - - - still good. 
Now close the second tab. 
Try to close the first tab - - - no popup, close button doesn't do anything. 
If you open another tab, it all works well again.

Does anyone have any ideea how this might be fixed?